# unable to fine AbstractTestNGCucumberTests class

Tags: java, testng, cucumber-java, test-runner

I have added dependencies in my pom file and still not able to extend `AbstractTestNGCucumberTests`

[image: plugins]

[image: dependency]

[image: Test]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a scope in your dependency?

If it looks like this

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
   <version>4.7.1</version>
   <scope>Test</scope>
</dependency>
```

delete that scope parameter, then you'll be able to use this dependency in the whole project.

Comment: now able to access AbstractTestNGCucumberTests with only later version up till 4.8.1 and but its now been deprceated "cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests' is deprecated  " anyone know how to implement this

Comment: You're using info.cukes, that's the old version of cucumber, you need io.cucumber, get it from maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest versions of maven cucumber and Test NG integration use
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
instead of
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

and ofcourse updated maven dependency to:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```